# How to study without having money

Tags: funding

What would be the best option for an EU citizen to study for a bachelor's degree (in any developed country: UK, EU, USA, AU, NZ, Japan, China etc.), without having the money to pay for fees, bills, accomodation etc.? Is there a study program, university or institution that provides funding through scholarships, financial aid or other means, and/or some kind of job position so that I can earn the money needed while studying?

After contacting many institutions I still haven't got a positive answer regarding such possibility. I have also read about need blind admissions, but these are very few USA colleges, with extremely low admission rates and other requirements.

Is it the only option available to just try enroll in one of these universities that have low fees, and then do your best to get a job in the city where the university is, and if you can't find any drop out and go back?

---

**Update**

@xLeitix said that:

> "[...] funded study places basically only exist for the PhD level."

While learning about the early life of [Jane Goodall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Goodall), I have read from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Goodall#Africa) paragraph that:

> [Louis] Leakey arranged funding, and in 1962 he sent Goodall, who had no
>   degree, to the University of Cambridge. She went to Newnham College,
>   Cambridge, and obtained a PhD in ethology. She became the eighth
>   person to be allowed to study for a PhD there without first having
>   obtained a BA or BSc. Her thesis was completed in 1965 [...]

Therefore she was able to get a PhD in 3 years, at Cambridge, without prior degree and on top of that without having to worry about money. Is this possible only if you manage to get in contact with someone at the level of [Louis Leakey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Leakey)? How can I skip all other degrees and just go for a PhD like Dr. Goodall, so that I can get funding like @xLeitix said?

Comment: It seems to me, most students have a job while studying. Would that be a problem for you?

Comment: I also think many unis have some money which they give as a present to good students but it's not impossible to list all of those stipends here. Have you checked whether the unis you are interested in have some stipends like this?

Comment: This is dangerously similar to a "shopping question". Should we specify that we do not want "shopping answers"?

Comment: @user111388 That would be a dream, not a problem. The problem is getting such job.

Comment: @user111388 Thanks for the reminder. I have contacted many of these universities but never heard of these stipends. I will look more into those.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni how can I remove the "shoppingness" from it?

Comment: @John I would suggest specifying that you do not want a list of specific programs, but just a description of how scholarships and funding systems for economically challenged students works in different countries.

Comment: @John: I belive getting a job is not so a problem. For example, museums often need students to watch the rooms (or the entrance). Or many work in bars, clubs, restaurants...

Comment: @John: From the article, it seems that only very few people have the "honor" to go for a phd without previous degrees. So you must be extraordinarily grear (in a few countries, political connections would also matter)

Answer (score 13):

In your circumstances, your best bet is likely to study in your home country. Many EU countries have stipends or student loan schemes targeted at qualifying local students that could otherwise not afford higher education. If you are willing to work next to studying, the world is basically your oyster anyway - many/most institutions in Europe allow students to work next to their studies even if the program is nominally full-time (of course the university does not look for a job for you, that would have to be your responsibility).

In your circumstances, moving to a *different* country to study will be a lot more challenging. Student loan schemes and stipends are often not available to foreign students, and funded study places basically only exist for the PhD level.

Comment: Are you sure about the last paragraphs? Shouldn't EU students be treated like nationals in other EU country (except for maybe some restriced studies like medicine)?

Comment: @user111388 Typically the eligibility for such schemes isn't based on citizenship, but often a student is required to have been a resident in the local country for some period of time. Two years, say. On the other hand it may be possible to get loans/stipends from one's own country for studies abroad, of course, with some restrictions.

Comment: @Anyon: Okay, interesting! I always thought this was irrelevant in the EU.

Comment: @user111388 Pretty sure, yes. Basically no country even in the EU will be happy to explicitly pay for the education of nationals from a different EU country, and all the ones I am familiar with (Austria, Germany, Sweden) have found hacks to restrict access to more or less their own citizens. What Anyon mentions is one of these hacks.

Comment: @xLeitix: Interesting! I googled yesterday and found this official looking site which seemed like it was in most cases not as you describe: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/education/university/admission-entry-conditions/index_en.htm Since you talk about Austria, as far as I know, many Germans and South Tyrolians study there - do they all have to pay the university fees?

Comment: @user111388 There is a difference between not paying fees and getting a stipend / loan. There are usually no fees (or at least not higher than for locals), but you also won't get money to study (i.e., pay for accommodation, books, food). In Austria, university fees are definitely the cheap part of studying. The expensive part is that you have to live while doing so.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible. At the Bachelor's level, your best option is to be really good and thereby qualify for scholarships. [Example at the university level](https://sfs.mit.edu/undergraduate-students/).

> At MIT, we admit the most talented students in the world through need-blind admissions. Once admitted, we meet your full financial need for all four years of your undergraduate career.

So once admitted, you're on easy street. Of course, to actually get admitted into MIT is very hard.

Various governments and/or organizations might also offer scholarships, although not all of them go to 100% of the costs. [Example in the EU](https://ec.europa.eu/education/study-in-europe/planning-studies/scholarships-costs_en), [example in New Zealand](https://www.studyinnewzealand.govt.nz/how-to-apply/scholarship/search-results).

In all examples you can expect that although the money is there, actually getting it will be very competitive.

Comment: im not sure if this is applicable for bachelor

Answer (score 2):

In Finland you can get the same support as natives if you are in the country for some other purpose than studying, such as working. For more information, see Kela's (Kansaneläkelaitos) website: https://www.kela.fi/web/en/financial-aid-for-students-eligibility

In Denmark it is possible to get the same support as native students get; see https://www.su.dk/english/su-as-a-foreign-citizen/. The most relevant method is likely https://www.su.dk/english/su-as-a-foreign-citizen/equal-status-according-to-eu-law/you-work-in-denmark/you-are-a-worker-or-a-self-employed-person-under-eu-law/, which stipulates:

> As a general rule, we expect that you as a minimum work 10 – 12 hours a week. Since the decisive point according to case law of the Court of Justice of the European Union is that the employment has lasted for a certain period of time, we also expect that you, as a starting point, have employment to this extent every week for a continuous period of 10 weeks.

I would suggest checking out other Nordic countries, too.

Answer (score 1):

Getting into the best school you can afford, I think, is a worthwhile investment. If you strongly believe that the schools in your home country do not offer what you need, then just keep trying.

Here are my recommendations: Some universities are more interested in international students than others, so, try to look up these types of institutions. Consider doing your degree online. This would save you from the burden of having to relocate. If you need to earn money in school, consider learning an in-demand skill that allows you to earn money while working remotely. If you do this, make sure you are capable of earning money before you relocate.

Do not try to relocate to another country, drop out and go back. That is simply not an option. It is a complete waste of your time, money, and mental/emotional resources. It may even damage your reputation. If you feel that you would be at significant risk of dropping out of a foreign university, you need to reevaluate your plan.